# req.query seems to return different values without change in code. How would I make it stable?

Tags: node.js, youtube, ejs

So I'm trying to make a Youtube video downloader using nodejs, express, ejs, and an API called ytdl-core.  The problem Im have is
sometimes the req.query will occasionally return undefined and it will produce this error

C:\Users\mattm\Desktop\YoutubeVIdeoDownloader\app.js:17
const videoid = req.query.url.split("v=")[1];
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

but when it works req.query returns an object with the key of 'url' and value of the inputted url
{ url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuJc-M35-r0' }

other times req.query returns an object with the key of 'link' and a value of the url

I'm not sure why this is happening.  I'm new to coding so it can be me not understanding the logic. Any help is appreciated!

```
const express = require("express");

const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const app = express()
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static("./public", { root: __dirname }));

// home page
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

//download page
app.get("/download", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query);
  const videoid = req.query.url.split("v=")[1];
  const info = await ytdl.getInfo(req.query.url);
  console.log(info.formats[1]);

  return res.render("download", {
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoid,
    info: info.formats.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.mimeType < b.mimeType;
    }),
  });
});

// 404 page
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).render("404");
});



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>YouTube Downloader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="heading">My Own YouTube Downloader</h1>
    <form method="get" action="/download">
      <input type="text" class="URL-input" placeholder="Video URL" name="url" />
      <button type="submit" class="convert-button">Convert</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know its not random but it seems that resetting the server seems to fix the issue sometimes. I've tried using body parser instead of query to no success.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to deal with your given issue, but here is my solution to this problem.

When req.query() is empty it returns undefined, and the split() method is running on the undefined value. So, first, we need to make sure that our req.query() contains the expected data on which we want to run the split() method.
To do so.

```js
app.get("/download", async (req, res) => {
  const reqQuery = req.query;
  if (req.query.url) {
    const videoid = req.query.url.split("v=")[1];
    const info = await ytdl.getInfo(req.query.url);
    console.log(info.formats[1]);

    return res.render("download", {
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoid,
      info: info.formats.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.mimeType < b.mimeType;
      }),
    });
  } else {
    res.json({
      message: "Something went wrong",
      error: true
    })
  }
});
```

In the solution instead of checking the **req.query()**, I checked the actual value.

Here is the reason. When we try to do a check on req.query(), and even if it's empty the if block will be executed. So always check the inner value of an object.

The mistake that we shouldn't make in our code while checking the object values.

```js
/* If block will be executed */
const reqQuery = {}

if (reqQuery) {
   console.log(true)
} else {
  console.log(false)
}


/* Best way */
const reqQuery2 = { url: 'https://dummyurl.com' }

if (reqQuery2.url) {
   console.log(true)
} else {
  console.log(false)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I used your solution to help find the root of my problem!I I realized that nodemon doesn't detect changes in ejs so I was trying to change things in ejs without restarting the server so I didnt understand how req.query worked. I was also using the back button instead of reloading the browser. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`req.query` will give you the query params that came on the request that arrives to the server on route `/download`. It's everything coming after `?`, for example:
`localhost:3000/download?v=something`

To make it "stable" you need to ensure you're calling it with query params in place, and have a validation in place for scenarios that query params werent provided.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I figured out the problem.  nodemon doesn't detect changes in ejs so I was trying to change things in ejs without restarting the server so I didnt understand how req.query worked.  I was also using the back button instead of reloading the browser.  Thanks again!